# run python script directly from command line

Tags: python, bash, shell, shebang, env

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I put that at the top of a script.  I've seen that should make the script runnable from the command line without the need for `python programname.py`.  Unless I'm misunderstanding I should be able to use `programname.py` as long as I have the above line at the top of the script.  Is this correct?

It isn't working for me I just get an error indicating that I would have to use `python` at the beginning of the 'call'.

Answer (score 26):

## Universal running of Python scripts

You can pretty much universally run without the shebang (`#!`) with

```
python myscript.py
```

Or nearly equivalently (it places the current directory on your path and executes the module named `myscript`) **(preferably do this!)**:

```
python -m myscript
```

from the command line, as long as you have Python installed and on your path environment variable (i.e. set to run with `python`, which, if installed, would typically be the case).

## Shebangs (`#!`) are a Unix thing.

The shebang, as you're using it, is typically for running on a Unix platform (typically Apple or Linux). Windows would typically require cygwin to use the shebang.

You can usually default to whatever python is available on your system path with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Assuming you're on a Unix, you might try other locations for your python setup, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

## Muddling through

You can see what python you're currently using by using the unix `which` command, so if you want to see where your python is coming from, use this command:

```
which python
```

or on Windows (cygwin probably can run the shebang):

```
where python
```

On Linux/Unix, you'll need execution perms to run the file as well, in that manner. Use chmod

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

(chmod also may apply to Cygwin in Windows)

If you're not running as root, you may require `sudo`, and that would be

```
sudo chmod +x myscript.py
```

And then attempt to run (within the same directory) with

```
./myscript.py
```

Comment: Python shebangs are no longer a Unix thing.  Python has implemented "virtual shebangs", which work validly on both Unix and Windows.  See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines

Answer (score 6):

make the file executable

```
sudo chmod +x /path/to/file.py
```

and then from the same directory as file.py:

```
./file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same: I could not run any executable files. Reason was that I had put a partition (my HDD) in `/etc/fstab` without [`exec` permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options). The solution was to change:

```
UUID=asdfasfasdfa /mnt/fee auto rw 0 1
```

to

```
UUID=asdfasfasdfa /mnt/fee auto defaults 0 1
```

because `exec` is included in `defaults = rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.`
On NTFS or other, you cannot change the permissions on files or folders in a partition, but that is not the OP's question, because permissions were set properly on the file.